# How to set Form control dynamiclly in angular material

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have now a problem, that I don`t know, how I set form control dynamically.
I will show you my code directly:

```
 <div [formGroup]="form">
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
              <input matInput type="text" [formControlName]="node.id" [(ngModel)]="node.field" [name]="node.id"
                     [matAutocomplete]="auto" placeholder="Field" (onChange)="fieldChanged(node.id)"/>
              <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let filteredFieldResult of locationFieldResults" [value]="filteredFieldResult">
                  {{filteredFieldResult}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
```

and the ts file:

```
 public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {


    filterService.dynamicFilterRawData.subscribe(data => this.nestedDataSource.data = data);
    this.form = this.createFormGroup();
    this.locationField.valueChanges.subscribe(inputField => {
        this.filterField(inputField);
      }
    );

 private createFormGroup(): any {
    const nodeIds = this.filterService.getNodeIds();
    const group = this.fb.group({});
    nodeIds.forEach((nodeId) => {
      group.addControl(nodeId, this.fb.control(''));
    });
  }
```

node.id is generated dynamically. 
in the funtion createFormGroup, there is getNodeIds(), which get all node ids and return a array.

my problem, How to connect node.id in formcontrolName with from group.

does anybody some solution?

Answer (score 0):

just add *ngIf and don't let anything that related to the form to render:

```html
 <div *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">
```

Comment: why ngig? I wanna also show the empty tree view, I just wanna delete all content.

Comment: try to return value from createFormGroup method.

Comment: I got this error : Cannot find control with name: "1.1"